# How to solve laravel/snappy error code 127?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-snappy

Recently, I have updated Laravel to version 7 and when I want to download a PDF from laravel/snappy, I get this error :

> The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:\nstderr: "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found\n"\nstdout: ""\ncommand: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --orientation 'landscape' --page-size 'a4' --encoding 'utf-8' '/tmp/knp_snappy5fa9279006a045.56009440.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy5fa9279006aaf0.09066361.pdf

Original code generating this error:

```
$data['company'] = $this->user->company->toArray();
$data['departments'] = $this->user->company->departments->toArray();

$this->prepareText($data);

/* @var $pdf PdfWrapper */
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('ticket.index', compact('data'))
    ->setOrientation('landscape')
    ->setOption('encoding', 'utf-8')
    ->setPaper('a4');
        return $pdf->inline(sprintf('Employee-Report-(%s).pdf', Jalalian::forge('now')
            ->format('Y-m-d')));
```

Answer (score 2):

The best option should be install wkhtmltopdf as an composer dependency
[install this](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#wkhtmltopdf-binary-as-composer-dependencies)

And after in config for an example config/snappy.php

```
 'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env(
        'WKHTML_PDF_BINARY',
        base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
    ),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],

'image' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env(
        'WKHTML_IMG_BINARY',
        base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64'),
    ),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Linux or macOS, run `$ which wkhtmltopdf` to find where the binary is stored on your machine (provided that you've installed the software).

Then, make sure `config/snappy.php` configuration points to that binary, see:

```
    'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [],
        'env'     => [],
    ],

    'image' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTML_IMG_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [],
        'env'     => [],
    ],
```

If you store your binary paths in `.env` file, you may need to clear the cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laradock and php 7.4 and got the same problem.
Just replace the code below in laradock\php-fpm\Dockerfile

```
ARG INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF} = true ]; then \
    apt-get install -y \
    libxrender1 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libx11-dev \
    libjpeg62 \
    libxtst6 \
    fontconfig \ 
    libjpeg62-turbo \
    xfonts-base \
    xfonts-75dpi \
    wget \
    && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.stretch_amd64.deb -O /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
    && dpkg -i --force-depends /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \
    && apt -f install \
;fi
```

Then,

```
docker-compose build php-fpm workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04/20.04 you can easily install it through:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RUN apt-get -y install fontconfig libx11-6 libxcb1 libxext6 libxrender1 xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base \
&& wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_2.1.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libjpeg-turbo8-dev_2.1.5-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu11_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu11_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8-dev_8c-2ubuntu11_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libjpeg8-dev_8c-2ubuntu11_amd64.deb \
&& wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg --ignore-depends=libjpeg-turbo8 -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer several times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @mepsd solution, there is an official solution as written on the [repository](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy?tab=readme-ov-file).

Move the binaries to a path that is not in a synced folder, for example:

```
cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 /usr/local/bin/
cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

Then your snappy.php should look similar to this:

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
    'timeout' => 300,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],

'image' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => env('WKHTML_IMG_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64'),
    'timeout' => 300,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

Answer (score -2):

I finally got the answer .
Problem is that i am using utf-8 for persian parsing and the only version of wkhtmltopdf which is working with that is 0.12.16-1 and as a result the binary directory which is responsible for saving the pdf is different in newer versions .

In conclusion, if you are using wkhtmltopdf and getting this error you should change the binary directory in your nginx (or your chosen web server ) to make it work